# Access denied to drupal via Azure Api management

Tags: api, azure, drupal

I have a Drupal deployed on a Bitnami Image containing some content that I use in a mobile application. For that, I sat a Rest API to request Drupal and get the data. 
Using Postman and the basic_auth credentials, I am able to get my API response properly with no problems. 
After that, I deployed Azure API Management and tried to pass the call of Drupal API through it, I provided the credentials via an authentication-basic policy, everything worked perfectly for a moment then suddenly I now getting a 403 Forbidden Access.
I still can request the Drupal API directly via POSTMAN using the same credentials with no problems. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, When I was creating the API on API Management, I used wrong authentication credentials many times for that, Drupal had blocked the API from access to the data.
I fixed that by doing a Truncate on the table flood of my database